# Always getting redirected from /authorized to /login page using new spring authorization server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I am using new **spring authorization server**. And everything was working fine with version 0.3.1. But after migration to 1.0.0. When I am trying to login (and I am supposed to be redirected to /authorized?code=) I am always getting redirected back to login. Could somebody please explain me what is going wrong? Maybe config for security should be specified in one place only?
Thank you.

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```java
package oauth2.config;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import oauth2.converter.AuthorizationClientConverter;
import oauth2.handler.FederatedIdentityAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import oauth2.repository.AuthorizationClientRepository;
import oauth2.repository.ClientRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimsSet;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2TokenType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.TokenSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtEncodingContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.OAuth2TokenCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.UUID;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationClientConverter authorizationClientConverter;

    @Autowired
    private FederatedIdentityAuthenticationSuccessHandler federatedIdentityAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
                new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
        RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher();
        http
                .securityMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(endpointsMatcher))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
        return context -> {
            JwtClaimsSet.Builder claims = context.getClaims();
            if (context.getTokenType().equals(OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
                claims.claim("claim", "zabur_claim");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(ClientRepository clientRepository) {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId("messaging-client")
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        AuthorizationClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new AuthorizationClientRepository(authorizationClientConverter, clientRepository);
        registeredClientRepository.save(registeredClient);
        return registeredClientRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .issuer("http://localhost:8080")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenSettings tokenSettings() {
        return TokenSettings.builder()
                .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                .build();
    }

    private RSAKey generateRsa() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        // @formatter:off
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    private KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```java
package oauth2.config;

import oauth2.handler.FederatedIdentityAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import oauth2.handler.FormLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import oauth2.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private FederatedIdentityAuthenticationSuccessHandler federatedIdentityAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private FormLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler formLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/signUp", "/logout"))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers("/logout", "/signUp", "/authorized").permitAll();
                auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.successHandler(formLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler))
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login.successHandler(federatedIdentityAuthenticationSuccessHandler));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

I am trying to login with OAuth2 and expecting to be redirected to the /authorized?code= but after that I am redirected to /login.

Answer (score 0):

Might you are using lot more code to serve your purpose. I integrated OAuth 2 in my Application using Spring security 6.0.0 and Spring Authorization Server 1.0.0. It made me sweating lot. But I got success. For that I shared my Authorization server configuration as it did.

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http
            .getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
    http
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(
                            new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
            )

            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
    http
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

I think it may help you a little bit or you may get an idea what actually going on in your code.

Comment: Hello, thank you. But I am trying to add federated identity login, so your example is invalid for me.

Answer (score 0):

SecurityFilterChain by default masks any request for authentication, it acts as a safety net, shadowing any `permitAll()` matcher. This is somehow not clear in the documentation, as per my understanding for the documentation, and needs to be better clarified.

Allowable paths must be declared in a SecurityFilterChain Bean, while authenticated and authorized paths must be kept in another SecurityChain Bean. To differentiate between allowed and authorized paths, use '.securityMaters()', as shown in the example below:

```
@Bean
@Order(0)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http
    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/signUp", "/logout"))
    .securityMatcher("/logout", "/signUp", "/authorized")
    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
        auth.anyRequest().permitAll();
    });
    return http.build();
}


@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http
    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/signUp", "/logout"))
    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
        auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
    })
    .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.successHandler(formLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler))
    .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login.successHandler(federatedIdentityAuthenticationSuccessHandler));
    return http.build();
}
```

Try it and let me know how it goes with you!